# Retopo shading layer issue

Tags: shaders

I'm new to sculpting and retopology and just completed the retopo of the original sculpt, however there are unusual shading layer sections that appear to almost be an additional thin layer which I'm unable to understand the reason for.

It is more noticeable with higher subdivision counts. Have I retopoligized incorrectly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello it's not clear what you are talking about, it looks like there are 2 mesh overlapping on the left? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/